# Python Get Stock Prices

Tags: python

I am working on a tutorial to pull different stock prices from Yahoo Fiances. I have this code which works but prints out the sentence the price of the different stock symbols and then the array brackets but not the prices. All help greatly appreciated.

```
import urllib
import re

symbolslist = ["aapl", "spy", "goog", "nflx"]

i = 0
while i < len(symbolslist):
    url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" + symbolslist[i] + "&ql=1" 
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    regex = '<span id="yfs_l84_' + symbolslist[i] + ' "> (.+?) </span>'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    price = re.findall(pattern, htmltext)
    print "the price of ", symbolslist[i], " is ", price
    i += 1
```

Comment: it's possible Yahoo changed their HTML since this code was written. Did you double-check that the span it's looking for is still there?

Comment: Why aren't you using a for loop; `for symbol in symbolslist:`?

Comment: your regex has an extra space before the close `"` and before and after your price

Comment: I'd probably use BeautifulSoup for HTML parsing as it has some in-built error correction and is much easier to use for these kind of use cases.

Comment: @Codin: please see my edit and pay attention to where I removed extraneous whitespace from and where I added missing whitespace for the code to be better readable.

Comment: pretty sure yahoo used to have an option to get prices as CSV -- if that still exists, it would simplify your life in terms of parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** on second thought, your regexp is not matching anything at all; please check if the regexp is correct to start with.

**EDIT2:** OK, looks like you're putting whitespace where it doesn't need to be (and not putting it where it should be). Please try to be tidier in the future when it comes to formatting your code, both for your own use but especially when showing to other people. The correct regexp is:

```
regex = '<span id="yfs_l84_' + symbolslist[i] + '">(.+?)</span>'
```

**Other than that...**

The simplest fix would be changing this

```
price = re.findall(pattern, htmltext)
```

to

```
price = re.findall(pattern, htmltext)[0]
```

because `re.findall` returns a list, not a single item, and the string representation of a list is `[bla, bla, bla, ...]`.

**Furhtermore**, in order to loop over a sequence of items, don't use a `while` loop with a manual counter and indexing—this is not assembler:

```
for symbol in symbols:
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you Erik you are correct my regex was written wrong the whole problem was I had a space between ' and ".

Comment: @Codin: you really need to work on writing stuff in general—just look at your last comment: not a single punctuation sign other than the one at the end, even though your comment consists of 3 sentences.

Answer (score -2):

maybe the space between ' "> is causing the problem

Comment: it's not difficult to try and execute the code so that you can give a sure answer and no maybes.